# SELECT multiple columns using mySQL prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql

This successfully retrieves the data from table, but this does not use a mySQL prepared statement.

```
$sql = "SELECT email, created_at, firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE id ='" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $email_address = $row["email"];
        $creatiom_time = $row["created_at"];
        $fname = $row["firstname"];
        $lname = $row["lastname"];
    }
}
```

How can I convert this into a prepared statement as to prevent SQL injection? My attempt at converting it does not retrieve the data.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT email, created_at, firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_SESSION['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($email_address, $creatiom_time, $fname, $lname);
$stmt->close();
```

What am I doing wrong? The email is unique, so this should only return one row; however, nothing is returned when I use the above prepared statement. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually store the row data into the bound result variables with [`fetch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php):

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT email, created_at, firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_SESSION['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($email_address, $creatiom_time, $fname, $lname);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
echo $email_address; // etc.
```

Note that you really should be checking the return status from these calls, particularly the `prepare`, `execute` and `fetch`.